# Tomcat Set CATALINA_OPTS in Windows Batch File

Tags: batch-file, tomcat, catalina

I'm trying to run a local instance of an application that runs on Tomcat 8.5.

Remotely the application runs on a Linux machine, but I need to specify the CATALINA_OPTS in a Windows batch file.

How would I specify (or rewrite) the following options in a batch file?

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -D<identifier>=<path-to-servlet-properties>" 
export CATALINA_OPTS
echo "Using CATALINA_OPTS: $CATALINA_OPTS"
```

I have tried the following:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS="%CATALINA_OPTS% <identifier>=<path-to-servlet-properties>"

exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you set the quotes earlier:

```
SET "CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS something something"
```

Note: no `EXIT`. The batch file is executed as part of the startup process, you don't want to interrupt it.